# Indefinite article with a superlative in case of ties

Tags: grammar, articles

Imagine there are several paths through a maze. Some path are shorter than others, and there can be several different paths with the minimal length.

If I talk about a path with the minimal length (I don't care which one from the set of paths with minimal length), should I say "the shortest path" or "a shortest path"?

Comment: I might be tempted to use "*a minimal [length] path*", but then again, the standard literature (e.g. papers on Dijkstra's algorithm) do use the construction "*a shortest path*".

Comment: **One of the shorter paths**. _'...then turn left down one of the shorter paths, and finally, turn right and you are in the centre of the maze.'_

Comment: I might say "...taking *any* of the shortest paths" to make clear that there are several, if that fact was not already established.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A shortest path.

Using 'The' would imply there is only one such path.